# Jquery Increase & decrease input automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few inputs and 1 has a standard value of 4.
And what I want to do is do -1 on INPUT A when I add +1 on INPUT B.

**Like** **this (what I want to replicate): https://gyazo.com/d0f289092a90c0976a4db61f90b5de7a**

My Inputs (only 3):

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <figure class="card card-product">
        <center><div class="img-wrap"><img src="SCHUTTING/schutting1.jpg" width="50%" length="50%"></div></center>
        <figcaption class="info-wrap">
          <center><h4 class="title">Scherm (17 planks) 16 mm - Grenen</h4></center>
        </figcaption>
        <div class="bottom-wrap">
          <div class="input-group input-number-group">
            <div class="input-group-button">
              <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
            </div>
            <input class="input-number" max="10" min="0" value="4">
            <div class="input-group-button">
              <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="price-wrap h5">
            <center><span class="price-new">$1280</span></center>
          </div> <!-- price-wrap.// -->
        </div> <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
      </figure>
    </div> <!-- col // -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure class="card card-product">
          <center><div class="img-wrap"><img src="SCHUTTING/scherm2.jpg" width="50%" length="50%"></div></center>
          <figcaption class="info-wrap">
            <center><h4 class="title">Schuin scherm links (17 planks) 16 mm</h4></center>
          </figcaption>
          <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <div class="input-group input-number-group">
                <div class="input-group-button">
                  <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
                </div>
                <input class="input-number" max="10" min="0" value="0">
                <div class="input-group-button">
                  <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <center><span class="price-new">$1280</span></center>
              </div> <!-- price-wrap.// -->
          </div> <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
        </figure>
      </div> <!-- col // -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure class="card card-product">
          <center><div class="img-wrap"><img src="SCHUTTING/scherm3.jpg" width="50%" length="50%"></div></center>
          <figcaption class="info-wrap">
            <center><h4 class="title">Schuin scherm rechts (17 planks) 16 mm</h4></center>
          </figcaption>
          <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <div class="input-group input-number-group">
                <div class="input-group-button">
                  <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
                </div>
                <input class="input-number" max="10" min="0" value="0">
                <div class="input-group-button">
                  <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <center><span class="price-new">$1280</span></center>
              </div> <!-- price-wrap.// -->
          </div> <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
        </figure>
      </div> <!-- col // -->
      </div>
</div>
```

And I want to do this with Jquery if possible. But I don't know how to call this (function) so I didn't find anything useful, and only got some vague javascript stuff but nothing in Jquery.

Hope you guys have some ideas

Comment: input type `number` will do the same

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara input type number will only increase or decrease the number in the current field not the "global" total/max in the first field.

Comment: @Jonathan Jake did you try anything in javascript at all ? if so please include it in your source, so that we can help you figure out where you might gone wrong